# combine multiple rows value in mysql table

Tags: mysql

How to get the following output in mysql table?

**source table:**

```
   id  values
    1    a
    2    b
    3    c
    4    d
    5    e
```

**Result:**

```
id  values
1    a
2    ab
3    abc
4    abcd
5    abcde
```

Comment: did you try anything...

Comment: And, what is your idea for achieving this?

Comment: Codeeeeeeeee.... We want code or anything you tried for helping you

Comment: What you try? Give code which you try to achieve this? have you any try?

Comment: I could not get exact code..

Comment: Please post the table schema like this Tablename(Field1,Field2)..

Comment: It would be much easier to generate your result set on application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.id, (@inc := concat(@inc, a.name)) AS Name
FROM  mytable a, (SELECT @inc:= '') c ORDER BY a.id ASC
```

[**SQLFIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd69d/1)

Comment: +1 although you should add `order by id` since you can't rely on an order unless you specify it.